# How much memory is affected from StreamReader

Tags: c#

When I use StreamReader as below, how much memory is affected. I presume since each line is read into a variable 'line', only that line remains in memory and that is overall a good thing. My purpose is not to burden memory too much when I read a very very large containing thousands of lines. A clarification will be appreciated.

```
string line = string.Empty;
using(StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\UK\Panfile.txt"))
{
    while((line = Reader.ReadLine())!= null)
    {
        //other code to process the line now being read.
    }
Reader.Close(); Reader.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: As a quick unrelated comment, you don't need to call Close and Dispose as you have wrapped the StreamReader in a using statement.

Comment: I am not too sure about the details of the memory consumption. However, I am sure it depends on the size of the file that you are trying to read via StreamReader. So as it varies from file to file, you can expect different memory usage for each file.

Comment: Would you @Benjamin make your point more clear. My file can contain hundreds of thousands of lines. Since only one line is kept in memory, how is the size of the file going to affect memory? I cannot fathom it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment on Reader.Close() and Dispose().

Comment: @Unnikrishnan, StreamReaders ReadLine reads All lines one by one  until there are no more lines to read. When you iterating through a large collection of cause it is going to consume a bigger amount of memory.
I highly recommend you to go through [this](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/the-fastest-way-to-read-and-process-text-files)  article to understand about reading and processing text file in C#.

Comment: I visted the site. I will definitely read it patiently. Thank you @Benjamin

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `StreamReader` will use [`byteBuffer.Length`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,69) of memory between calls. If you have not specified a default it uses `1024` bytes. It also allocates a `char[] charBuffer` of size `encoding.GetMaxCharCount(bufferSize);` which allocates two bytes per element in the array.

If you do not pass in a `Stream` object and let it generate it's own `FileStream` it will use a default filestream buffer of `4096`.

The [`ReadLine` call itself](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,a4ada5f765646068) will allocate a `StringBuilder` internally and will read data into the `byteBuffer` then decode the bytes and store it in the `charBuffer`, it will then copy the chars out of the `charBuffer` and into the `StringBuilder` which then is returned to you via a `.ToString()` call.

So in summary, `new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\UK\Panfile.txt")` at rest it will will allocate `1024 + (1025 * 2) + 4096`<sup>1</sup> bytes of memory (5120 total), and during the `ReadLine` call it will allocate at most an additional `line.Length * 2 + StringBuilderOverhead + line.Length * 2`<sup>2</sup>. The `*2`'s you see are for the `char[]` because each `char` takes up two bytes.

---

<sup>1:`byteBuffer` + `charBuffer` + the `FileStream` buffer</sup>
<sup>2:The `char[]` internal to the `StringBuilder` + Any slack space in the string builder buffer + the string returned by the `.ToString()` call.</sup>

Comment: So great of you @Scott Chamberlain. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a great answer ! Con you provide sources ?

Answer (score 4):

It will only hold 1 line in memory at a time so this method is perfect for processing large files without eating up lots of memory.

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much @mbrdev for your answer. Great.